# Outlook Message webLink with ispopout=0 working only with Inbox

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently building an integration with Office 365 Outlook thanks to the Microsoft Graph API. I retrieve user messages data, along with the `webLink`, which is a direct URL to the message in Outlook Web App.

By default, it opens in a popout window displaying only this message. My goal is to display it in the full Outlook Web App. In the [documentation of a Message resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message), Microsoft states this:

> You can append an ispopout argument to the end of the URL to change how the message is displayed. If ispopout is not present or if it is set to 1, then the message is shown in a popout window. If ispopout is set to 0, then the browser will show the message in the Outlook Web App review pane.

Doing this works well if the e-mail is in the Inbox mail folder. However, if it is in another folder (like Sent Items or a custom one), it always redirects to the Inbox and opens the first message in it.

Is it a known limitation of this parameter? Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Best regards!

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As you have seen, I posted the question on [Microsoft Docs repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2860), but I didn't get any response.